# locations to save files which can be accessed on app

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to supply a bunch of files with my Windows Phone 8.1 app which are necessary for running the application. I searched on the net and found that [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx). But I don't know which place in particular is the ApplicationData.Current folder. What I want is the following:-

1. Can I **create a folder called Resources** or use the existing Assets folder in my Project tree and **save the files** in there.
2. If yes, then how can I **access that folder** from within my App i.e. how can I **open and close files** in that Directory(relative or absolute **addressing format to be used**)? If you can provide a one or two line code for this, it would be great.
3. Do I have to use the **ReadTextAsync method** to read the entire text of the file into a string or are there any other methods.(The **System.IO.File.ReadAllText() method is not accessible** when creating Windows 8.1 Phone app).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App is installed on SD or Phone, depending on user Settings on the Phone. You can't normally access those files eg. by browsing files while Phone is connected to computer - the apps are *Isolated*.

Depending on your App:

- if it's 8.1 Silverlight then you will find all the information [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
- if it's 8.1 RunTime then [take a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx).

Although you can't access files inside your App from outside the App, from WP8.1 you have access (read/write) to SD Card and other KnownFolders.

EDIT - you can also access your files by using [Uri schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx).

Comment: @Romasz...After the app is put on phone, the files would be accessed by the app during runtime on phone. The files would also be there on the phone. The files are just Xaml files which will change the app's look depending on the buttons pressed.

Comment: @avinash Are you targeting Silverlight or RunTime? Have you looked at MSDN - there are many examples and simple tutorials.

Comment: @Romasz...It is not a Silverlight app that is for sure...I don't know the actual name for my app's category but in VS 2013, the project was labelled Windows Phone under Windows Store(under C#) category...The reference I am following is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn631251.aspx

Comment: @avinash Then you are targeting RunTime - [use the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx) and [this describing reading/writing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx). It also depends on what kind of file you want to access (Resource/Content/Other), but surely all the information you should find at MSDN.

Comment: @avinash Those files you want to access - are created during runtime of the app or they are created by you? If they are created during runtime then you should be able to access them by Uri with `ms-appdata` if they are Rsources then use Uri with `ms-appx` should help. See also edit in the answer. Also [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) may help you.

Comment: @Romasz...they are created by me

Comment: @avinash Look maybe also at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465228.aspx). Please take look at those MSDN links, try some things and then tell what is not working.